# foreach like solution in dynamically created fields / Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have dynamically created inputs for which i need to run function from legacy code.
This is why I need something that would allow me to run single function for each of the dynamically created field (id).

```
foreach ($("input[id^='dynamicInput_']" as singleInput) {
        do_something(singleInput);
}
```

There are lots of questions related to dynamically created fields, but none of them provides similar solution. 
I will appreciate possible ideas.
Thanks.

Based on KostasX answer i made this:

```
$("input[id^='dynamicInput_']").each(function(){
  doSomething(this);
});
```

and it precisely does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `jQuery`, you can use the .each() method on the element list and apply the function on each element:

```js
$("input[id^='dynamicInput_']").each(function( index, singleInput ){


  doSomething( singleInput );

  // Or wrap the singleInput in a jQuery object to execute jQuery methods:

  doSomething( $(singleInput ) );

});
```

Comment: it relates to singleInput as this. and it did a trick. Thanks.